# LOGOUT button not showing after successful REGISTER/LOGIN, ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a issue where I register/login a user in ASP.NET Core application, I then get redirected to what should be the index page with a LOGOUT button, however this is not the case.

I am using HTTP Post in order to Log the user out as recommended,

Here is my Account Controller with Register,Login and Logout:

```
namespace ProjectApplicationX00140684.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(Register model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Copy data from RegisterViewModel to IdentityUser
                var user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email
                };

                // Store user data in AspNetUsers database table
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                // If user is successfully created, sign-in the user using
                // SignInManager and redirect to index action of HomeController
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }

                // If there are any errors, add them to the ModelState object
                // which will be displayed by the validation summary tag helper
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


                // Store user data in AspNetUsers database table
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password,
                    model.RememberMe, false);

                // If user is successfully created, sign-in the user using
                // SignInManager and redirect to index action of HomeController
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }

                // If there are any errors, add them to the ModelState object
                // which will be displayed by the validation summary tag helper

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");

            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my _Layout.cshtml Logout form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager;


                        @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">
                                    <button type="submit" style="width:auto"
                                            class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
                                        Logout @User.Identity.Name
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
                                    Register
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">
                                    Login
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        }


                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You mean it still shows the Register/Login button instead of Logout button.Could you show your startup.cs code ?And make sure the `app.UseMvc` is placed behind the `app.UseAuthentication`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. Here is my startup.cs as requested.

https://pastebin.com/P4vRcmqX

Answer (score 2):

You may forget to add `app.UseAuthentication()` before `app.UseMvc()` in `Configure` method

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```